# Interger .ToString() is null when value =0 Blazor

Tags: blazor-webassembly

[image]

Why interger .ToString() is null when value is 0? Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: Show your whole code plz.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Counter page, which it looks like you are using, and a screen capture of the Auto at the break point.  As you can see s is not null.  What are you not showing us?

```
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    string s = "";
    int i = 5;
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        int j = i;
        s = currentCount.ToString();
        currentCount+=i;
        // Break point here
    }
}
```

And a screen capture of the Autos:

[image]